# How do I interpolate between points so that the interpolation function is injective and smooth?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

I have a set of $n$ points, $\left\{ \left(x_i,y_i\right) \right\}$, where for all $i$ (except for $1$ and $n$),
$x_{i-1} < x_i < x_{i+1}$ and $y_{i-1} < y_i < y_{i+1}$.

What I want to do is to construct a function $f:[x_1, x_n]\mapsto [y_1, y_n]$ that

1. satisfies $f(x_i)=y_i$ for all $i$
2. is injective
3. is at least twice differentiable (but ideally more).

Linear interpolation is not differentiable. Lagrange polynomial or spline interpolation cannot be guaranteed they are injective (usually not). I found one question in this site but I am not sure if this is what I want, given that it is not an interpolation, while mine does not necessarily require it to be a single polynomial over the domain ( [Polynomial fitting where polynomial must be monotonically increasing](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60610/polynomial-fitting-where-polynomial-must-be-monotonically-increasing) ).

Is there a way to make an interpolation function that is guaranteed to be injective and smooth?

Edit: Thanks to QiaochuYuan's comment, I add another detail. I want this function to have a minimal number of inflexion points. With the worst possible data, it would have $n-3$ inflexion points (as lonza leggiera pointed out). So I guess a "good" interpolation should have inflexion points no more than $n-3$, or whatever the minimum number of points that data can allow, while being twice differntiable. Specifically, the problem I concern right now only involves 5 points, and it seems possible to have only 1 inflexion point for the given data.

Comment: If this is all you want to do you can start with the linear interpolation, then replace the function at each point, where it looks like a corner, with a smoothed out corner however you like. Whether this is useful for anything depends on what you want this for.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan OK. I think an additional constraint would be the minimal number of inflexion points -- thus requiring the second order derivatives to exist. What I'm dealing with is usually close to a Gaussian cumulative distribution, so only one inflexion point would be ideal.

Comment: It would be impossible to interpolate an injective function through the points unless $\ y_{i+1}=y_i\  $ whenever $\ x_{i+1}=x_i\ $ and $\ y_{i+1}>y_i\ $ whenever $\ x_{i+1}>x_i\ $. If your points do satisfy these conditions you might as well eliminate any duplicated  $\ x,y\ $ pairs so that you have a set of  $\ x_i,y_i\ $ for which $\ x_i<x_{i+1}\ $ and $\ y_i<y_{i+1}\ $ for all $\ i=1,2,\dots,n\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera Edited as you suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn’t monotone spline interpolation do what you want? There are many variations available, but you can start reading about a simple approach [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation).

Answer (score 0):

$\def\eqdef{\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}}$
Not an answer, but a couple of observations that are too long for comments.

- If $\ f\ $ is twice continuously differentiable then it can be *forced* by your data to have *at least* $\ n-3\ $ inflection points. By the mean value theorem, for each $\ i=1,2,\dots,n-1\ $ there must exist $\ \xi_i\in\big(x_i,x_{i+1}\big)\ $ such that
  $$
  f'(\xi_i)=\frac{y_{i+1}-y_i}{x_{i+1}-x_i}\ ,
  $$
  and then for each $\ i=1,2,\dots,n-2\ $, there must exist $\ \zeta_i\in\big(\xi_i,\xi_{i+1}\big)\ $
  such that
  \begin{align}
  f''(\zeta_i)&=\frac{f'(\xi_{i+1})-f'(\xi_i)}{\xi_{i+1}-\xi_i}\\
  &=\frac{\frac{y_{i+2}-y_{i+1}}{x_{i+2}-x_{i+1}}-\frac{y_{i+1}-y_i}{x_{i+1}-x_i}}{\xi_{i+1}-\xi_i}\ .
  \end{align}
  Since $\ \xi_{i+1}>\xi_i\ $, the sign of $\ f''(\zeta_i)\ $ is the same as that of $\ s_i\eqdef\frac{y_{i+2}-y_{i+1}}{x_{i+2}-x_{i+1}}-\frac{y_{i+1}-y_i}{x_{i+1}-x_i}\ $ and so if $\ s_i\ $ and $\ s_{i+1}\ $ are of opposite signs then there must be a point of inflection of $\ f\ $ lying between $\ \zeta_i\ $ and $\ \zeta_{i+1}\ $.  Therefore, the number of points of inflection that $\ f\ $ will be *forced* to have is the number of sign changes in the sequence $\ s_1,s_2,\dots,s_{n-2}\ $, which will be $\ n-3\ $ if the signs of $\ s_i\ $ alternate. For $\ n=5\ $, therefore, it's possible that $\ f\ $ could be forced to have at least two inflection points.
- Apart from the the fact that you might not be able to have as few inflection points as you might have wanted, I'm certain that you can achieve the rest of the properties you have specified with [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation).  I suspect they're achievable with a *cubic* spline, but if that's true, the proof doesn't appear to be easy.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. For the first point, I agree that yours is the least number of inflexion points given such data, and my estimation was incorrect. On the other hand, that is still the worst case, and given better data, I think I would be able to produce better interpolation with fewer inflexions.
For the second point, that is exactly the reason I wouldn't use spline. But apart from that, what I've experimented didn't look that promising to be always injective.